# Printing HTML links from an ArrayList in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, jena

I'm a newbie to JSP and WebApp.

I'm having problem printing out some HTML links stored in an ArrayList on my JSP.

Here is the JSP code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<% 

List<Resource> list = new ArrayList<Resource>();

list = (ArrayList<Resource>) request.getAttribute("URIlist");

for (Resource uri: list) {
%>
<a href="${uri}"> ${uri}</a>
<br>
<% 
}
%>
```

I'm sure the ArrayList is correctly istanciated (I tried to simply System.out.println() and everything worked). I guess the problem is the ${uri} thing but i don't know how to fix it.

Just to be clear: links I have to print looks like this           "http://localhost:8080/LAB5/rest/luoghi/Chiesa_di_Sant_Eligio_Maggiore"

Answer (score 0):

If the URIlist is available in the request score, use conditional tags or javascript for DOM element creation.